# Get Facebook multiple variations of Video ID from URL using RegEx in PHP

Tags: php, regex, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

This question has been asked numerous times on Stack Overflow and I've looked around a lot, but all answers I've found only finds it for one variation of the Facebook URL, but I need to be sure that you can use any of the variations that can be used.

- https: //www.facebook.com/username2/videos/100000000000000
- http: //www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=107084586333124
- http: //www.facebook.com/photo.php?more=diffictult&v=107084586333124
- http: //www.facebook.com/?v=107084586333124

This is what I got so far, but it's doesnt quite work as I expect,
https://regex101.com/r/sC6oR2/6

> ^https?://www.facebook.com/(\?v=\d+)|(.*?/videos/(\d+))$

I am not too familiar with RegEx but as I searched around I tried to make the best out of it. I've also looked in to using **parse_url()** and I've heard that it would be better than RegEx but since Facebook has many different types of URL:s.

I would highly appreciate some help with this since I've spent most of the day trying to get this to work, when I get one part to work I don't get the other one - and it've left me with a mild headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really that difficult, there are only two types of formats that you have described.

- videos/id
- ?v=id

So if it has 'videos', then just grab the last digits, and if it as ?v, grab the v from the url.

```
<?php

$urls = ['https://www.facebook.com/username2/videos/100000000000000',
         'http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=107084586333124',
         'http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?more=diffictult&v=107084586333124',
         'http://www.facebook.com/?v=107084586333124'];

$ids = [];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $tmp = explode('/', $url);
    if (strtolower($tmp[count($tmp) - 2] == 'videos')) {
        $ids[$url] = $tmp[count($tmp) - 1];
        continue;
    }
    parse_str(parse_url($url)['query'], $query);
    if (!empty($query['v']))
        $ids[$url] = $query['v'];
}

print_r($ids);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/8f4d117e418a10):

```
Array
(
    [https://www.facebook.com/username2/videos/100000000000000] => 100000000000000
    [http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=107084586333124] => 107084586333124
    [http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?more=diffictult&v=107084586333124] => 107084586333124
    [http://www.facebook.com/?v=107084586333124] => 107084586333124
```

Here's a function just for this:

```
function getID($url) {
    $tmp = explode('/', $url);
    if (strtolower($tmp[count($tmp) - 2] == 'videos'))
        return $tmp[count($tmp) - 1];
    parse_str(parse_url($url)['query'], $query);
    if (!empty($query['v']))
        return $query['v'];
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Nice! This didn't even occur to me - I was so stuck in trying to find it using RegEx. Thank you, I appreciate your help it a lot!

Comment: Thank you for helping in this issue, we have another format in facebook if you can kindly help `https://www.facebook.com/LovehelloU/videos/vb.172573132808153/1156989764366480/?type=2&theater` plus how can i filter it for single URL rather than array.

Comment: @MoxetKhan I needed the same thing, and I used answer and modified it slightly.
Try something like this: http://pastebin.com/4b2hShyC I wish you luck! :)

Comment: @Jimmy thank you for the snippet, i resolved the issue with my own logic. Let me try yours if it is more pro and valid.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

/**
* Get video id from any facebook video URL
* funcion by Mohamed Elbahja
*/
 function fbvideoid($url) {
    // delete space in url
    $url =  str_replace(' ', '', $url);
    // parse url
    $pars = parse_url($url);
    $path = $pars['path'];

    // delete end slashe
    if($path[strlen($path) - 1] == '/'):
        $path = rtrim($path, '/');
    endif;

    $count = count(explode("/", $path));
    // type url
    $urltype = "";
    if ($pars['path'] == "/photo.php" || $pars['path'] == "/video.php" || $pars['path'] == "/"):
        $urltype = 2;
    elseif($count == 4):
      $urltype = 3;
    elseif($count == 5):
        $urltype = 1;
    endif;

   // get id
    if ($urltype == 1) {

        $ex = explode("/", $path);
        $videoid = $ex[4];

    } else if ($urltype == 2) {

        parse_str($pars['query'], $e);
        $videoid = $e['v'];

    } else if ($urltype == 3) {

        $ex = explode("/", $path);
        $videoid = $ex[3];

    } else {
        $videoid = null;
    }

   return $videoid;
}

    // example :) 

echo fbvideoid('https://www.facebook.com/username2/videos/107084586333124'); 

echo "<br>";

echo fbvideoid('http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=107084586333124');

echo "<br>";

echo fbvideoid('http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?more=diffictult&v=107084586333124');

echo "<br>";

echo fbvideoid('http://www.facebook.com/?v=107084586333124');

echo "<br>";

echo fbvideoid('http://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=107084586333124');

echo "<br>";

echo fbvideoid('https://www.facebook.com/LovehelloU/videos/vb.172573132808153/107084586333124/?type=2&theater');
```

Comment: Could you explain your code? Just posting code as an answer isn't *that* helpful...

Comment: demo in example :) 
sorry i speak english a little

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression:

> videos/(\d+)+|v=(\d+)|vb.\d+/(\d+)

and then remove from the string "videos/" and "v="

https://regex101.com/r/sC6oR2/64